# compojure-api return value schema or error

Tags: clojure, compojure, plumatic-schema, compojure-api

[compojure-api](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api) allows you to define the `return` schema:

```
(s/defschema Pizza
  {:name s/Str})

(GET "/pizza/:id" [id]
  :return Pizza
  :summary "returns a Pizza"
  (ok (get-pizza id)))
```

My issue is when the `get-pizza` fn returns a 404 `{:status 404 :body {:message "Invalid id provided"}}` the response (to the requester) is that that 404 does not match the `Pizza` schema:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "name": "missing-required-key",
    "status": "disallowed-key",
    "body": "disallowed-key"
  }
}
```

The [docs](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/wiki/Building-Documented-Apis#response-models) show that you can provide multiple response schemas but I am unclear on what my `get-pizza` fn should return in order to utilize those schemas. Their example uses the ring-http-response lib to generate the return values, but there is no difference between my return value for `get-pizza` and the [ring-http-response 'not found' fn](https://github.com/metosin/ring-http-response/blob/e472a7b7d7f963dda7ada440ab11729243f07996/src/ring/util/http_response.clj#L268).

Truthfully I would rather not use the `:responses` param if possible because I can already foresee all the code duplication. Before specifying the `:return` Schema I was able to have my `get-pizza` fn return a 404 and be correctly passed onto the requester but once I added the Schema I was no longer able to do that. I considered having the return value be `:return (s/one Pizza Error)` where `Error` would be a generically defined error map but I don't see why I would do this for *every* route if all calls could in theory return a 500.

Note: The reason I switched to utilizing the `:return` param is that it makes the generated swagger-ui docs much prettier & easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

You have a small issue in your code I assume as you didn't show implementation of your `get-pizza [id]` function.

You return `{:status 404 :body {:message "Invalid ID provided}}` which is then wrapped into HTTP 200 response by `(ok (get-pizza id))`.

Your `get-pizza` function should return a pizza or nil if not found. Your HTTP response should be generated based on that in your route:

```
(GET "/:id" []
  :path-params [id :- Long]
  :return Pizza
  :summary "Gets a pizza"
  (if-let [pizza (get-pizza id)]
    (ok pizza)
    (not-found {:message "Invalid ID provided"})))
```

[The original example from compojure-api repo](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/blob/e9810fdfb3a77483cfafd182c1b4189a37a37626/examples/thingie/src/examples/pizza.clj#L64) has a bit different implementation where for `nil` values from `get-pizza` it will still return HTTP 200 response with empty response body. According to your question you would return 404 instead and the code above should meet your requirement.

Comment: The code above returns the same error because the response of `not-found` does not match the defined `:return` value of the `Pizza` schema. It does work when I do `(s/maybe Pizza)` but it seems unreasonable to have to wrap *all* of my return values in `s/Maybe` when not all of them will return 200s. `get-pizza` lives in another file and i want the `get-pizza` fn to be able to return a 404 that this path definition will then properly process and was wondering if there was a way with compojure-api to do *and* still have a defined return fn since it doesn't seem to be an unreasonable use case.

Comment: Did you change the route definition to use `not-found` when `nil` pizza is returned? You can try with a modified example from my fork:
`git clone https://github.com/pbzdyl/compojure-api`
`cd compojure-api`
`git checkout stackoverflow-35618493`
`lein run`

Then in another terminal:
`curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/pizzas/1000`
and you will get HTTP 404 and the message.

Comment: There was an error in your code that didn't let it run but using not-found works. My question though is that I want a way to just have `(get-pizza id)` return the response i want rendered (status code and all). Otherwise for every single route I will have to separately check for 200,404,409 etc

Comment: Could you provide more info what error you were getting? Regarding your concern to have your `get-pizza` to render the whole response - this way you are moving the same problem deeper into your code. Now your handler generates the response using `ok` or `not-found` and you want to generate responses manually as maps in `get-pizza` function.

Comment: It was a local dependency issue, it runs now! And I found an example in their wiki that has a similar approach except it has a separate fn wrapping that `get-pizza`, this is the approach I will go with since for most of the routes I have to handle more than just 200s & 404s https://github.com/JarrodCTaylor/authenticated-compojure-api/blob/master/src/authenticated_compojure_api/route_functions/user/create_user.clj#L17